# Sliding Window Normalization

Tags: preprocessing, normalization

I've been reading about time series forecasting and many approaches use a sliding window method. What I don't get about it is how to properly normalize your data. Most codes I've seen so far normalize the data *before* slicing the windows and that doesn't seem right, because every input will rely on an information that exists outside of it (mean and standard deviation). When I'm about to make a prediction, all I have is a single window. If I'm going to normalize it, I have to do it using it's own data, otherwise I'd have to know what were the statistics used when fitting the model, so that my input stays in the same "scale" as the training data, but I don't see people worrying about that. So, in my understand, every window should be normalized *after* the slicing, using it's own data, and not before, relying on the whole dataset. Is that correct?

Comment: Welcome to DataScienceSE. I'm not experienced enough with time series to give a precise answer, but I can at least clarify one point: it's ok to normalize across instances using statistics from the training set, and then apply the same normalization (using the same statistics *from the training set*) on every instance in the test set. In theory the test set follows the same distribution as the training set, that's why this makes sense. That doesn't mean that it must be done this way (this depends on the problem and data), but it's possible.

Comment: Thank you. I understand it's ok. My point is that I've never read anywhere people discussing this. Maybe that's a thing everybody supposes everyone else knows and because of that no one talks about it...

Comment: I don't think there is anything that everybody is supposed to know. Imho the problem is that resources about data science/ML tend to be either very general at beginner level (so they don't address this kind of specific detail) or quite specific at advanced level (so they often focus on the specific problem/technique rather than details about normalization). I think it's due to the field being very recent, very broad, and constantly evolving. so it's a bit messy, myself I often learn new things that I feel I should have known years ago. well, we live and we learn :)